# while i launching Presto server using $ bin/launcher run i am getting error

Tags: ubuntu, presto, trino

Unrecognized VM option 'G1HeapRegionSize = 32M' Did you mean 'G1HeapRegionSize='? Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

You should write your JVM option as:
`G1HeapRegionSize=32M` instead of `G1HeapRegionSize = 32M` in your `jvm.config` file in presto.